# RandomForestRegressor spitting out 1 prediction only

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to work with the RandomForestRegressor. Using the RandomForestClassifier I seemed to be able to receive variable outcome of +/-1. However using the RandomForestRegressor I only get a constant value when I try to predict.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from pandas_datareader import data
import csv
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = pd.read_csv('C:\H\XPA.csv')
data['pct move']=data['XP MOVE']
# Features construction
data.dropna(inplace=True)
# X is the input variable
X = data[[ 'XPSpread', 'stdev300min']]
# Y is the target or output variable
y = data['pct move']
# Total dataset length
dataset_length = data.shape[0]
# Training dataset length
split = int(dataset_length * 0.75)
# Splitiing the X and y into train and test datasets
X_train, X_test = X[:split], X[split:]
y_train, y_test = y[:split], y[split:]
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
# Create the model on train dataset
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
data['strategy_returns'] = data['pct move'].shift(-1) * -model.predict(X)
print(model.predict(X_test))
```

Output:

```
[4.05371547e-07 4.05371547e-07 4.05371547e-07 ... 4.05371547e-07
 4.05371547e-07 4.05371547e-07]
```

The output is stationary while the y data is this:

```
0       -0.0002
1        0.0000
2       -0.0002
3        0.0002
4        0.0003
          ...  
29583    0.0014
29584    0.0010
29585    0.0046
29586    0.0018
29587    0.0002
```

x-data:

```
       XPSpread  stdev300min
0           1.0       0.0002
1           1.0       0.0002
2           1.0       0.0002
3           1.0       0.0002
4           1.0       0.0002
...         ...          ...
29583       6.0       0.0021
29584       6.0       0.0021
29585      19.0       0.0022
29586       9.0       0.0022
29587      30.0       0.0022
```

Now when I change this problem to a classification problem I do get a relative good prediction of the sign. However when I change it to a regression I get a stationary outcome.
Any suggestions how I can improve this?

Comment: Well, either you have a *classification* problem and you use a classifier, or a *regression* one and you use a regressor. Why should both approaches work? What is your problem - regression or classification?

Comment: I have a regression problem, which I could change to a classification problem. Hence I used the RandomForestRegressor, however the current outcome is not optimal at all. Y_train dataset is:```0       -0.0002
1        0.0000
2       -0.0002
3        0.0002
4        0.0003
          ...  
22186   -0.0003
22187    0.0007
22188    0.0001
22189   -0.0003
22190   -0.0003```
So having a stationary outcome is not what I expect and looking for.

Comment: Didn't say that a stationary outcome is acceptable, of course; you sure all these indices (`0, 1,..., 22189, 22190`) have not been passed as data (as they have here)?

Comment: No not really, one of things I noticed that I might have done wrong was: ```data.dropna() --> data = data.dropna() ```

Comment: I think the `inplace=True` should have done the job as expected

Comment: In any case, I guess an independent look and assessment of your situation was arguably not unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

It may very well be the case that, with only two features, there is not enough information there for a numeric prediction (i.e. regression); while in a "milder" classification setting (predicting just the sign, as you say) you have some success.

The low number of features is not the only possible issue; judging from the few samples you have posted, one can easily see that, for example, your first 5 samples have identical features (`[1.0, 0.0002]`), while their corresponding `y` values can be anywhere in `[-0.0002, 0.0003]` - and the situation is similar for your samples #29583 & 29584. On the other hand, your samples #3 (`[1.0, 0.0002]`) and #29587 (`[30.0, 0.0022]`) look very dissimilar, but they end up having the same `y` value of `0.0002`.

If the rest of your dataset has similar characteristics, it may just not be amenable to a decent regression modeling.

Last but not least, If your data are in any way "ordered" along some feature (they look like, but of course I cannot be sure with that small a sample), the situation is getting worse. What I suggest is to split your data using [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), instead of doing it manually:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
     X, y, test_size=0.25, shuffle=True)
```

which hopefully, due to shuffling, will result in a more favorable split. You may want to remove duplicate rows from the dataframe before shuffling and splitting (they are never a good idea) - see [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).